# Tkinter callback in a class

Tags: class, python-2.7, tkinter

I understand concept callback button  in function and procedure.How to apply this code in class?I have problem about callback button in Tkinter for get value from class.I can't access callback method.Eror program = callback not define.

```
from Tkinter import *
class Program: 
    def __init__(self):
         self.root = Tk()
         self.root.title("Sample")
         self.display = Entry(self.root)
         self.display.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5)
         Button(self.root, text="Proces", width=5, foreground="blue", command=callback).grid(row=4, column=0)


    def callback(self):
         print hello

program = Program()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is use: `command=self.callback` instead of `command=callback`.

Also, it should be `print "hello"`

Comment: If you find my answer informative & helpful,kindly [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. Its a way of telling people that you have found the answer. No obligations,however :)