# Python callback in a class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I found code text summarization in Github, and I will change this program became Tkinter program.I have problem when will get value in class using Button widget and show result in Text widget.How to get value of method summarize in this code use Tkinter button?I usualy only use function or procedure nothing class and method.This code already running in intrepreter.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


class NaiveSummarizer:


    def summarize(self, input, num_sentences ):

        punt_list=['.',',','!','?']
        summ_sentences = []

        sentences = sent_tokenize(input)
        lowercase_sentences =[sentence.lower() 
            for sentence in sentences]
        #print lowercase_sentences

        s=list(input)
        ts=''.join([ o for o in s if not o in  punt_list ]).split()
        lowercase_words=[word.lower() for word in ts]
        words = [word for word in lowercase_words if word not in stopwords.words()]
        word_frequencies = FreqDist(words)

        most_frequent_words = [pair[0] for pair in 
            word_frequencies.items()[:100]]


                # add sentences with the most frequent words
        for word in most_frequent_words:
            for i in range(0, len(lowercase_sentences)):
                                if len(summ_sentences) < num_sentences:
                                        if (lowercase_sentences[i] not in summ_sentences and word in lowercase_sentences[i]):
                                                summ_sentences.append(sentences[i])
                                                break


        # reorder the selected sentences
        summ_sentences.sort( lambda s1, s2: input.find(s1) - input.find(s2) )
        return " ".join(summ_sentences)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    naivesum = NaiveSummarizer()
    text='''
    To see a world in a grain of sand,
    And a heaven in a wild flower,
    Hold infinity in the palm of your hand,
    And eternity in an hour.

    A robin redbreast in a cage
    Puts all heaven in a rage.

    A dove-house fill'd with doves and pigeons
    Shudders hell thro' all its regions.
    '''
text2 = '''
         You conclude with the aphorism of Hippocrates, "Qui gravi morbo correpti dolores non sentiunt, us mens aegro­tat" (Those who do not perceive that they are wasted by seri­ous illness are sick in mind), and suggest that I am in need of medicine not only to conquer my malady, but even more, to sharpen my senses for the condition of my inner self. I would fain give you an answer such as you deserve, fain reveal myself to you entirely, but I do not know how to set about it. Hardly do I know whether I am still the same person to whom your precious letter is addressed. 
'''
print(naivesum.summarize(text2,3))
print(naivesum.summarize(text,2))
```

Comment: Why don't you add the code from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23262238/1639625) and what's not working with that? Don't expect us to write the entire GUI for you.

Comment: I did not mean it.
I only ask for sample code on the same problem.
and I can learn from the code to be applied to my case
using the class and take the value of the class using tkinter
or a website address for my study, thank a lot

Comment: But in your other question you already added a callback to a button. Why can't you use your `callback` function to call the `summarize` function and put the result into the text field?

Comment: I have implemented the code that I asked earlier by summarize code text.
And the following error appears: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):    what happened with my code?please explain with me, thanks
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: summarize() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I newbie in python, please explain more for me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly use the `summarize` function as a callback for your button; instead you should wrap it into another function that calls `summarize` and then displays the result in the Entry widget.

First, you have to add a [text variable](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) to you widget so you can read and write the text, like this:

```
self.outputvar = StringVar()
Entry(self, textvariable=self.outputvar)
```

Now you can add a `callback` function to your button, like in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23262238/1639625), doing this:

```
def callback(self):
    text = "lorem ipsum" # get actual input text, maybe from another widget
    num = 3              # get proper value for whatever this is for
    result = self.summarize(text, num) # call summarize
    self.outputvar.set(result)         # show results in your widget
```

Alternatively, you could use a [`Text`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html) widget; here, [inserting text](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html) is handled differently though.